# ZeroMQ architecture for REQ-REP style with (sometimes) long task

Tags: architecture, zeromq

I am a beginner in ZeroMQ and about to choose an architecture for a simple IPC client-server application.

Initially it is a simple **`REQ-REP`**, without any performance needs, answering to clients on the same machine. For one message type, the answer is quite long to compute.

When dealing with this compute, the server still needs to answer other requests. The rest of the requests doesn't need to be made asynchronously, they can be synchronous, as the number of requests is very low.

From what I read in the ZeroMQ guide, I need some broker that will distribute messages to a special background worker for the long task, and all other messages to another worker.

I thought about **`DEALER-ROUTER`** architecture, but I don't clearly see if the two workers will be **`REQ`** or **`DEALER`** workers, and what is the type of the broker.

**What should I choose for the architecture here?**

Answer (score 1):

> *(cit.):* **What should I choose for the architecture here?**

Let's agree first, that any decision about using a `REQ/REP` or `DEALER/ROUTER` pair of behavioural archetypes is just a step to use a pair of two compatible items from a set of possible candidates, that match one common ZeroMQ/RFC-definition ( one cannot do less - as any choice of non-matching behavioural archtetypes would yield a crashing nonsense ).

As said, this is by far **not** a choice of **architecture**.

---

### The Best Next step?

A best next step you may do for this is **IMHO** to get a bit more global view, which may sound complicated for a newbie, but not a man with your scope of professional experience , but if you at least jump to the **page 265** of the [**Code Connected, Volume 1 [*asPdf*->]**](http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main%3Afiles/cc1pe.pdf), if it were not the case of reading step-by-step there.

The fastest-ever learning-curve would be to **have first an un-exposed view** on the **Fig.60** *Republishing Updates* and **Fig.62** *HA Clone Server pair* for a possible High-availability approach and then go back to the roots, elements and details.

[image]

---

### Better define all needs well before opening a box with ZeroMQ candys:

Need a **non-blocking** operation?
Never use a `REQ/REP` tandem, even if recommended, as it can fail into an unsalvageable deadlock.

Need a **scaling**?
Better design with workload-distributing proxy, as it can scale-out way more, than a monolythic SPOF.

Need a remotely **distributed EoW-like inspectable** agent?
Better design agents with a by-design sort of mini-SoftRealTime-embedded schedulers included.

These are the sort of success-critical high-level drivers, that an attempt to sketch an architecture will need.

[image]

Distributed systems design is closer to a symphony composition, where cooperation and multi-level control-loops are making **The Difference** between a Chernobyl-type of management failures and robustness and resilienece shown during Appolo-11 moon-landing crisis solution. These lectures from bright and/or poor designs clearly show that an architecture is never anything close to sketching a few, [pure-**`[SERIAL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) SLOCs of an imperative code. Never.

There are no easy shortcut paths from nuts & bolts level-of-detail view to successfully land and remotely control a Curiosity-type robot device on MARS.

Rather the very opposite approach works ( and the nuts & bolts are but results, but here, being well sure to safely match the principal goals ).

---

### Define all needs first

and then may enjoy the powers of drawing a feasible architecture to meet ( and better exceed ) all the defined expectations together ( even if "*XP*" or "*Agile*" evangelisators try to make you believe that it is not necessary -- it is.

A poor architecture decision is hell-expensive and none "*agile*" promoter will ever be able to pay all the costs of the finally crashed Mars orbiter or just the lost revenues from poor project management, due to re-engineering delays right from forgotten / wrong initial assumptions )

---

Wish you good luck and enjoy all the powers of smart designed distributed systems at least as much as I did during the last two decades - definitely worth one's time and efforts.

Comment: Not sure of what to do with your answer, but thanks for your time! Will read it carefully and think about it.

Comment: :o) Not sure of what to do with your question, but always better to learn from previous mistakes, than to repeat the same paths that have lead to ( already visited ) errors. The book is out of question great. Good Luck and better never permit a single blocking-mode ( *sync* ) operation.